# Syntax Error On Boolean @ expected

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When isAlertPresent() command is used it gives syntax error on boolean @ expected. The code used was

```
public boolean isAlertPresent(){

  boolean presentFlag = false;

  try {

   Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
   presentFlag = true;
   alert.accept();

  } catch (NoAlertPresentException ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }

  return presentFlag;

 }
```

The error shown is 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Syntax error on token "boolean", @ expected
    isAlertPresent cannot be resolved to a type
    Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeaderName
    Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatement

How to rectify this error?

Comment: Please share the error log with us.

Comment: The error is coming in eclipse, the boolean is marked in red colour and when mouse is kept over that, the error is displayed. Error displayed is "Sysntax errror on token "Boolean", @ Expected".

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Syntax error on token "boolean", @ expected
 isAlertPresent cannot be resolved to a type
 Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeaderName
 Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatement

Comment: It looks like java Selenium has a class named IsAlertPresent.  I suspect that may be the reason for your compilation error.  Maybe try changing the name of the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is no need to use **presentFlag** variable in your method.

This method works fine for me:

```
public boolean isAlertPresent() 
{ 
    try 
    { 
        driver.switchTo().alert(); 
        return true; 
    }    
    catch (Exception e) 
    { 
        return false; 
    }    
}
```

Hope it would help you ;)